# about accesskey in JSF 2

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have  the next code:

```
<h:form name="frm">
<h:panelGroup>          
<p:commandButton value="Good" id='good' action="#{job.SetGood}" accesskey="g"/>
<p:commandButton value="Bad" id='bad' action="#{job.SetBad}" accesskey="b"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And i need that the user can "press" the button with id='good' using just the key Space, and the button with the id='bad' using the key "backspace" I try many stuff but is not working...  for example I try calling the function cargar() on load  and is not working... somebody can help me?

```
function cargar()
{
document.getElementById("good").focus();
document.onkeypress=function(e)
{
var esIE=(document.all);
var esNS=(document.layers);
tecla=(esIE) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
if(tecla==32)
{
frm.submit();
 <!--Also I try: document.getElementById("good").click();-->
}
};
}
```

Comment: accesskey is to getfocus r u getting focus on 'g'

Comment: yes, but what i need is, that when I press Space, the button got press...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the attribute prependId:

```
<h:form name="frm" prependId="false">
```

This will render the button like

```
<button id="good" name="good" ...
```

If you use stay with the default (prependId="true") the button will be rendered like

```
<button id="j_idt14:good" name="good" ...
```

where in this case j_idt14 is the id of the parent form component.

The javascript function will propably not find an element in your code `document.getElementById("good")`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this.

```
<h:form name="frm">
   <p:remoteCommand name="executeAction" listener="#{job.SetGood}" update="frm" />
  <h:panelGroup>          
     <p:commandButton value="Good" id='good' 
          accesskey="g" onfocus="executeAction();" />
     <p:commandButton value="Bad" id='bad' action="#{job.SetBad}" accesskey="b"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

`<p:remoteCommand` will be executed when your `<p:commandButton` will get the focus.

Comment: I did that you said but now when the button receive the focus, he is loading and loading (loop) all the content, and i need first; always button good will be pressed (or submit) when the user press the key space... it means: The page load.... then the button get focus so the user will check something and if he think he need to press the button he will just press space and then will lost focus...